# Has anyone successfully installed Syspro on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine

I know that Syspro ERP software only officially supports windows, but has anyone successfully installed the client on Ubuntu? Perhaps using Wine?

Comment: Below is the only reference I could find related to Syspro and Wine. The clients seems to work but only there is no installation how-to on the web so you are on your own. Do consider installing virtualbox, windows in it and Syspro on that if you have troubles installing it with WINE.

Answer (score 1):

The place to look for software working with WINE is [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2316). It has this to say:

> Syspro is an extensive Accounting / Inventory package including P.O.S interface, xml, ODBC interfaces. Written in Cobol. **Officially client program cannot run in Linux. BUT, it works with Wine!** The SYSPRO product offering includes a choice of more than 40 application modules, ranging from accounting, sales, purchasing, inventory, ABC (Activity Based Costing), Web Services, APS (Advanced Planning, Scheduling), RMA (Return Merchandise Authorization) Remote Site Interface to Engineering Change Control (ECC), CRM/SRM (Customer Relationship Management/Supply Relationship Management), EDI, Bar Coding, and Product Configuration. **Server officially can be run in Linux, so that wasn't tested in wine.**

And when you click the "version" at the bottom:

**PCs used**

- a variety of machines, including P4 3Ghz with 256 Ram, Celeron 1.7Ghz with 128 Ram, AMD Duron 1100 with 256 Ram. OS was either Fedora3 or Fedora4
  Wine compatibility

**What works**

- Reports, queries, everything that was tested worked as soon as "font substitution" was done, and the correct fonts were selected within the program for "List Views"

**What doesn't work**

- fonts need substitution: a key must be added HKLM\Software\ ... \fonts and at HKLM\ ...\ WindowsNT\fontsubsitutes otherwise you get errors about "MS Sans Serif point size:008" not being captured.
- Printing also is partially successful. Within the program "Windows Printing" must NOT be selected or the program will crash when you print. INSTEAD, the built-in printers of the program should be selected, and those printers should be set up to "Print to Server", the server then maps an LPT to \client-machine\printer so that reports can be printed.
- Last bug, for unknown reason, it was found that one of the many users listed cannot successfully log in, although any of the other users can do so, even on the same machine.

---

App. version: 6.00 release 8

Wine version: 20050524:

Installs?: yes

Runs?: yes

Rating: Silver

Comment: Some feedback: The comment "Officially client program cannot run in Linux. BUT, it works with Wine!" is misleading. Comment from Syspro was that "if you can get it to work using an emulator, then good for you. But it is not supported and we will not guarantee that future changes will mean that it will continue to work".

So do not try this in a production environment: either use dual boot or a VM such as Virtual Box.